# Replace column between two files in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How can i replace the 6th column of my following data.fam file as following with 3rd second column of my .txt file.

My `data.fam` file looks like this

```
20481 20481 0 0 2 -9
20483 20483 0 0 1 1
20488 20488 0 0 2 1
20492 20492 0 0 1 1
20493 20493 0 0 1 -9
20498 20498 0 0 2 -9
```

`data.txt` file looks like this.

```
20481   2 1
20488   2 1 
20483   2 1 
20493   1 0 
22822   2 1 
20498  -9 -9
22692   1 0
```

The `output.fam` should be like

```
20481 20481 0 0 2 1
20483 20483 0 0 1 1
20488 20488 0 0 2 1
20492 20492 0 0 1 0
20493 20493 0 0 1 0
20498 20498 0 0 2 1
```

I have tried `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$6=a[$3]}1' data.txt data.fam >output.fam`
But the output is without the 6th column as following  at all like the following. Where i am doing wrong??

```
    20481 20481 0 0 2 
    20483 20483 0 0 1 
    20488 20488 0 0 2 
    20492 20492 0 0 1 
    20493 20493 0 0 1 
    20498 20498 0 0 2
```

Comment: In the "expected output", why is there a `1` in the 6th row?  Where does that come from?

Comment: In the sample `data.fam`, $3 is always 0.  There is no row in `data.txt` in which $1 is zero, so `a[0]` is undefined.  So `$6 = a[$0]` is always setting `$6` to the empty string.  I don't know what "3rd second column means", so I can't tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: the data i presented here in example is hypothetical. Just a representative of my original one. Main question is how to replace column in one file with second files column to be precise.

Comment: @WilliamPursell i want to replace the 6th column of data.fam with third column of data.txt. Sorry a biologist here.

Comment: I think you want `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3; next} {$6=a[$1]}1' data.txt data.fam`, but I don't understand where the 1 comes from in the 20498 row of the sample output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell can you explain this command line for my better understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236188/discussion-between-aryh-and-william-pursell).

Comment: No chat.  SO likes to dissuade extended discussions to their own detriment.  The whole purpose of these posts is for future readers to be able to follow the discussion.  I'm not sure I can explain it any better than a basic awk tutorial.  You want the 6th value to take the value that was stored in the array keyed by the first column of the current row, not the 3rd column of the current row.  The index should be `$1`.